# which SSL certificate is used when embedding a form in an Iframe

Tags: iframe, ssl

I'm embedding a credit card form on my website using an iFrame.

My site and the site that is hosting the form have SSL certificates.  but which SSL certificate is being used during the interaction with the gateway.

Is there such thing as MSSL?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean which SSL *certificate* is being used?

Comment: Yes, which SSL is used in communicating to the gateway

Comment: I've already asked you what you mean by that. If the answer to my question is 'yes' it is incomprehensible why you are now repeating the same incorrect statement I was asking you to clarify. Your question is about *certificates.* Don't misuse standard terminology.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't make much sense.

The SSL *certificate* used by a host is the one that is installed at the host.

I have no idea what you mean by MSSL. I don't see the point of inventing acronyms and asking whether they mean anything.